# MessageBox.Show in UI Thread

Tags: c#, wpf

```cs
this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
    () => {
              MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("111111111111111111111111", "Child process failed", MessageBoxButton.OK);
          }
);

this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
    () => {
              MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("22222222222222222222222", "Child process failed", MessageBoxButton.OK);
          }
);
```

**Why does it show 2222222222 first and then show 11111111111?**

If I change `this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` to `this.Dispatcher.Invoke` the order will be right. Does anyone know why?.

Comment: You are sending MessageBox.Show to the dispatcher. It will execute 11111 first but won't wait until you click OK, it will show the 22222 ontop of that. So the order seems right.

Comment: When the first MessageBox ("22") appears, try to move it to the side. The other MessageBox should be behind it.

Comment: If you care about the order then you need to change your technique, Maybe add messages to a queue and process them from there.  If this mimics a real world requirement then messagebox is unlikely to be your best choice to show multiple messages.

Comment: I want to know Why it won't wait until I click OK when it executes 11111 first.

Comment: ***When the first MessageBox ("22") appears, try to move it to the side. The other MessageBox should be behind it ***

No, must click OK and then the 1111 show.

Comment: var op = this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(...); op.Wait();

Answer (score 0):

`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` is essentially putting a message on the message queue, asking for the method to be run when the UI thread is free.

While the messagebox is showing some messages will still be processed, and this message is probably one of them. So the first messagebox will be displayed first, and a moment later the second one, on top of the first. When you click away the second messagebox it looks like the first one appears.

`this.Dispatcher.Invoke` is also putting a message on the message queue, but in this case the caller is also waiting for the UI thread to process the message before continuing, so the messageboxes are shown one after the other and not on top.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
I have debug it. The break points always run into 11111（but at here the message box does not show） and then run into 2222, and then the message box always show 222 first and then 1111.

Comment: @yunate I revised the answer. The messageboxes are probably showing on top of each other.